# Spring Data Rest - content field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm in the process of making an api with spring data rest and am a little confused on the fields generated in a response and was wondering if there is a way to get rid of some of them. I have set the media type to APPLICATION_JSON and a response of many items has three fields:

1. links (an array for links to the first page, next page, last page, etc.)
2. content (an array of the data)
3. page (info on the page)

I want all of these fields, however, each object in the content array also has the content and link fields which are completely unnecessary. The links point to itself and the content is always empty. Here's an example of an item that's returned:

```
{
  "id" : 9,
  "positionNumber" : "F38520",
  "openDate" : "2014-11-11T05:00:00.000+0000",
  "description" : "Research: This position is responsible for research related activities including, but not limited to, research design and implementation, preparation of grant proposals to both intramural and extramural funding sources, both collaborating on and leading manuscript development for submissions to peer-review journals.",
  "type" : {
    "title" : "Teaching and Research Faculty",
    "code" : null
  },
  "category" : null,
  "recruitmentType" : {
    "name" : "Public"
  } },
  "content" : [ ],
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "https://localhost/v1/items/9"
  }, {
    "rel" : "item",
    "href" : "https://localhost/v1/items/9"
  } ]
}
```

Also, the media type has to be APPLICATION_JSON, so I can't just set it to use hal+json. I've looked everywhere for an answer to this. Can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you found how to exclude content[] from response?

Answer (score -2):

You need use this  jar  **jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar** and apply annotation on your DTO , by which you are making json for eg .

```
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  // this will not include null members of class in json 
  @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)   // this will not include empty members of class in json
```

you can apply them on class level as well as on class member level .

for eg .

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) 
public class myDto {

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) 
public Content[] content;
```

}

Comment: It's Spring Data REST so there are no DTOs

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't actually have "content" or "links" in my class. Those fields are generated by spring